# Computing the gradient of "l2 regression"

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

Given an invertible matrix $G \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$, what is the gradient of the following function w.r.t. $x$:
$$ \left\| Gx\right\|_2^2$$

Also, is this function smooth!?

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the function in terms of the inner/Frobenius product (which I'll denote with a colon) 
$$f=\|Gx\|^2_F = Gx:Gx$$

Then finding the differential and gradient is pretty straightforward
$$\eqalign{
 df &= 2\,Gx:G\,dx \cr &= 2\,G^TGx:dx \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 2\,G^TGx \cr\cr
}$$